# I need to modify the source code from my static page

Tags: static-website

I created two pages Home (static) and Blogs ( Where all my post goes). For some reason I can not make my static page to display on a side column my resent post entries.  I want to modify the static code from my home page to be able to display a side column.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked at [the template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to determine which of your theme templates that page uses?

Comment: You need to confirm what is the template file your page is using.

Probably its 'page.php' or something like that.

Then you need to edit it, and add the code for the sidebar.

You'll probably need to copy the sidebar code from your blog template page, wich probably will be 'blog.php'

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, are you asking how to show say the 5 most recent posts? Or how to embed that in post content? Or are you asking how to edit a themes template?